# cakephp 2.x: how to pass data to the views

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: informations [APP/View/Information/index.ctp, line 2]
```

I have this function in my controller

```
public function index($slug){
         $this->layout = 'sbhealth';
         $this->loadModel('Menu');
         $informations = $this->Menu->findBySlug($slug);
         if($informations){
            $this->set('index', $informations);
         }else{
            return $informations = "not find";
         }   
    }
```

I need to pass datas to my view "index.ctp" index.ctp will then find the ID in my array to pass it to an Element. but the View doesn't recognize "$informations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably doesn't constitute something that should be on StackOverflow, since it's specified in great detail in the book, but...

```
// in your controller
$this->set('informations', $informations);
```

The first item is the name of the variable that will be available in the view.

The second item is the value you want to put in that variable.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the help, My bad, I tought the first one was the view I was thinking like in Codeigniter :(!

Comment: thks! I have to wait some couple of minutes!